# Locked Caching using Cache Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

We have code below we use to improve performance. It works fine, but every few days we start receiving a ton of exceptions (below). It's not related to volume, but it's random.

Comment: /// Performs the locked code to produce the result if necessary while thread locking it and then caching the result.

line 45 is:  lock (_keys.First(k => k == key))

Any Ideas?

Code:

```
    public class LockedCaching
{
    private static List<string> _keys = new List<string>();

    public class Result
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public bool ExecutedDataOperation { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the locked code to produce the result if necessary while thread locking it and then caching the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="expiration"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Result Request(string key, DateTime expiration, RequestDataOperation data)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            return new Result { Value = data(), ExecutedDataOperation = true };
        }

        //Does the key have an instance for locking yet (in our _keys list)?
        bool addedKey = false;
        bool executedDataOperation = false;
        if (!_keys.Exists(s => s == key))
        {
            _keys.Add(key);
            addedKey = true;
        }
        object ret = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        if (ret == null)
        {
            lock (_keys.First(k => k == key))
            {
                ret = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
                if (ret == null)
                {
                    ret = data();
                    executedDataOperation = true;
                    if(ret != null)
                        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, ret, null, expiration, new TimeSpan(0));
                }
            }
        }
        if (addedKey)
            CleanUpOldKeys();
        return new Result { Value = ret, ExecutedDataOperation = executedDataOperation };
    }

    private static void CleanUpOldKeys()
    {
        _keys.RemoveAll(k => HttpContext.Current.Cache[k] == null);
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception
>   of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   key at System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoGet(Boolean isPublic, String
>   key, CacheGetOptions getOptions) at PROJECT.LockedCaching.b__8(String
>   k) in PROJECT\LockedCaching.cs:line 64 at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveAll(Predicate`1 match) at
>   PROJECT.LockedCaching.CleanUpOldKeys() in
>   PROJECT\LockedCaching.cs:line 64 at
>   PROJECTLockedCaching.Request(String key, DateTime expiration,
>   RequestDataOperation data) in PROJECT\LockedCaching.cs:line 58 at
>   FeaturesWithFlags1.DataBind() at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Web control where it's used - This web control requests a list of locations from a webservice. We use this lockedcache request almost everywhere we call the webservice.:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    try
    {
        string cacheKey = "GetSites|";
        mt_site_config[] sites = (mt_site_config[])LockedCaching.Request(cacheKey, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        () =>
        {
            WebServiceClient service = new WebServiceClient();
            sites = service.GetSites();
            service.Close();
            return sites;
        }).Value;
        ddlLocation.Items.Clear();
        ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please Select"));
        ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem("Administration"));
        ddlLocation.Items.AddRange
        (
            sites.Select
            (
                s => new ListItem(s.site_name + " " + s.site_location, s.th_code.ToString())
            ).ToArray()
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.Error("ContactUs Control Exception: Exp" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
    }
    base.DataBind();
```

}

Thank you for your comments. ConcurrentDictionary was the way to go. The issue to why we received errors was because the linq code "lock (_keys.First(k => k == key))" was returning an exception rather than null. Using the concurrentdictionary will be much safer and hopefully not cause any lock issues.

Modified Code:

```
public class LockedCaching
{

    public class Result
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public bool ExecutedDataOperation { get; set; }
    }

    public static Result Request(string key, DateTime expiration, RequestDataOperation data)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            return new Result { Value = data(), ExecutedDataOperation = true };
        }

        object results = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        bool executedDataOperation = false;

        if (results == null)
        {
            object miniLock = _miniLocks.GetOrAdd(key, k => new object());
            lock (miniLock)
            {
                results = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
                if (results == null)
                {
                    results = data();
                    executedDataOperation = true;
                    if (results != null)
                        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, results, null, expiration, new TimeSpan(0));

                    object temp;
                    object tempResults;
                    if (_miniLocks.TryGetValue(key, out temp) && (temp == miniLock))
                        _miniLocks.TryRemove(key, out tempResults);

                }
            }
        }
        return new Result { Value = results, ExecutedDataOperation = executedDataOperation };
    }

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _miniLocks =
                              new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

}
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to lock on an expression? Do you think that your code actually _locks_ the first element? That's not how `lock` works.

Comment: Your code is extremely non-thread-safe.  You should use a ReaderWriterLock, or just use a single `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: if `_keys` is supposed to be a list of syncroots used specifically for locking purposes, then `_keys` would need to itself be locked while accessing the collection.  Although I'm not really sure what the intent is looking over your code.

Comment: I disagree with @JohnSaunders. This lock does indeed lock the first matching element in the collection. At does not lock the expression.

Comment: @Slaks I think the `HttpContext.Current.Cache` collection is already thread-safe. Hard to imagine it isn't.

Comment: @AndrewArnott: Yes, but his logic is not thread-safe, especially with the `_keys` list.

Comment: It does not lock the first matching element in the sense of preventing simultaneous access to it. In this code, _keys is being used as a collection of locks, and this places a lock on the first lock out of that collection that matches the string `key`.

Comment: @SLaks ah yes. We can't see what type `_keys` is from the code snippet. It must be either thread-safe or locked to protect it from multi-threading.

Comment: @AndrewArnott: Given `Exists()` and `RemoveAll()`, it's almost definitely `List<T>`.

Comment: I added more detail to the post to hopefully answer all of your questions. Please re-read. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a race condition on the collection. You write to it concurrently. This can have all kinds of effects.

```
_keys.Add(key);
...
_keys.RemoveAll(k => HttpContext.Current.Cache[k] == null);
```

There are other races as well. You probably should revise expand the amount of code that you put under your global lock. Be careful not to destroy too much concurrency by using that global lock.

Maybe you can switch to a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<CacheValue>>`. This is the canonical pattern for a cache that works like yours. It does not suffer from cache stampeding.

Be careful with threading. It is easy to introduce subtle races like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing indicates that `_keys` has a null element in it. From your code snippet this shouldn't happen. So either other code we can't see is adding nulls, or you have a thread safety issue. Since you almost certainly have thread-safety bugs (see question comments) I'd start looking there.